# How can I reformat UV maps for baking so there are no overlapping UV maps. (For export to Unity)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv, unity, baking

I'm currently using cycles render and I've created two materials for my wave object, and have baked each to an external image. However, I want to combine the baked images into the same bake so I can export it as a texture to Unity.

[image: front side of model]

[image: back side of model]

All I could seem to do was combine the individual UV maps of my textures, so they overlap, which is not what I want for a bake.

[image: combined uv maps]

This is the resultant image when I baked the UV maps:

[image: bake result]

How can I separate my UV maps in such a way that they can be on the same baked image, but will also map to my texture correctly when I export my model to Unity?

[This is my .blend file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9bKRFjWdwARMGlHbUpHaUNnX1k)

Comment: Use Smart UV Project if you don't want to take the time to use seams correctly ;)

Comment: The problem is, when I use Smart UV Project my textures change position on my model.

Comment: Then make a new uv map in the mesh settings in the properties window. Use one for the bake and one for the textures.

Comment: Yeah that's what I did. I found a tutorial about it after i posted this. Thanks though, that was the right suggestion.

Comment: Figured it out. Had to create a new UV map in the mesh settings in the properties window. Used one for the bake and one for the textures. Thanks [psycoder](http://blender.stackexchange.com/users/28015/pycoder)